# HTML5 video not starting on iOS9 (iPad)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html5-video

First of all, **I know about the fact that a video on a website, under iOS, will play only on user action** (unless a click event is set).

I have a HTML5 video element:

```
<video muted="muted" loop id="js-b2b-video">
    <source src="my_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Then, in JS, there's a piece of code listening to the `scroll` event of the window:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {

    var $video = $('#js-b2b-video');

    // Check if the video is in the viewport
    // and if YES, play it:
    $video.get(0).play();

});
```

The code above works on Windows and macOS - in Chrome, Edge, Firefox and Safari. However, on any browser running on **iOS9** (e.g. on iPad 1) - nothing happens, the video does not start.

So, I tried to simulate a click:

```
 // Listener
 $('#js-b2b-video').on('click', function() {

   $(this).get(0).play();

 });

  // Modified scroll listener
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {

    var $video = $('#js-b2b-video');

    // Check if the video is in the viewport
    // and if YES, play it:
    $video.click();

});
```

And nothing. Hitting the wall.

I need to be able to start the video on iOS without the user interaction. What am I missing?

PS. Tapping (clicking) on the video doesn't start it either.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @CBroe told you in his comment, read the link he put (motivation part):

> A note about the user gesture requirement: when we say that an action must have happened “as a result of a user gesture”, we mean that the JavaScript which resulted in the call to video.play(), for example, must have directly resulted from a handler for a touchend, click, doubleclick, or keydown event. So, button.addEventListener('click', () => { video.play(); }) would satisfy the user gesture requirement. video.addEventListener('canplaythrough', () => { video.play(); }) would not.

So it basicaly says that you cannot use any event or action from the user to start playing the video.

Then your 'scroll' event cannot work ^^